# Spring reactor doOnNext, is it getting executed?

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I was playing around with reactor

```
public @NotNull Mono<ServerResponse> findXXXXSse(final ServerRequest request) {
    return request.bodyToMono(XXXXSearch.class)
            .doOnNext(this::validate)
            .flatMap(this::findXXXXSse)
            .switchIfEmpty(this.emptyBodyException());
}
```

And I was wondering if the use of `.doOnNext(this::validate)` was correct or not. From my point of view, I'm not sure the validate is called before the `findXXXXSse`?

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Flux.doOnNext` method should always be used as a side-effect.

The documentation says "Add behavior (side-effect) triggered when the Flux emits an item." Refer : https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#doOnNext-java.util.function.Consumer-

I assume you want to resume your chain only when the validation is successful, i.e.,  `.flatMap(this::findXXXXSse)` should only be called if validation succeeds.

You can use `filter(this::validate)` and add a `validate(XXXXSearch.class)` method to return true/false.

Comment: Thanks @Avik, not sure to get it, with what I wrote I could get in the flatMap before the doOnNext action is executed ?

Comment: I like the filter approche thought

Comment: Your doOnNext method will be executed before flatMap. doOnNext typically keeps an eye on Observable so that you could know what's going on inside your reactive chain.

Comment: Remember doOnNext cannot modify your reactive chain. So typically with what you wrote, if your validation fails inside doOnNext, you will have to throw an Exception to stop the flatMap from being executed.